# How to access a possibly existing element derived from a JSON data tree?

Tags: python, data-structures, exists

I have a rather complex data structure derived from JSON with `json.load(<filehandle>)`, e.g.

```
{
    "sensors": {
        "measurements": [
            [
                null, 
                null, 
                null
            ], 
            [
                {
                    "sensor": "Fields 341", 
                    "remote": null, 
                    "mark": "reliable", 
                    "duration": 81.54296875
                }, 
                {
                    "sensor": "Fields 341", 
                    "remote": null, 
                    "mark": "reliable", 
                    "duration": 61.54534875
                },
                {
                    "sensor": "Fields 341", 
                    "remote": null, 
                    "mark": "reliable", 
                    "duration": 61.89378945
                }
            ]
        ]
    }
}
```

The result are nested dictionaries and lists, e.g.

```
{u'sensors': {u'measurements': [[None, None, None],
                            [{u'duration': 81.54296875,
                              u'mark': u'reliable',
                              u'remote': None,
                              u'sensor': u'Fields 341'},
                             {u'duration': 61.545348750000002,
                              u'mark': u'reliable',
                              u'remote': None,
                              u'sensor': u'Fields 341'},
                             {u'duration': 61.89378945,
                              u'mark': u'reliable',
                              u'remote': None,
                              u'sensor': u'Fields 341'}]]}}
```

The goal is to take the data and stuff it in a database via sqlalchemy. Like this:

```
for item in sensors["measurements"]:
    for j in range(len(sensors["measurements"])):
        DBTable.DBField = item[j]["sensor"]
        ...
```

The problem with this is: Any parts in the data could be replaced with `null/None` in case the measurements where erroneous (like the first one). If so the DBFields should be assigned `None`. If this is the case the assignment raises an exception:

```
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is unsubscriptable
```

Is there a sane way to get the for loop to run without raising the exception (maybe using .get() of somekind)? If not, what is the best way to handle this non-existent data structures?

Answer (score 3):

You can preconstruct a dictionary with defaults that you like:

```
defaults = {"sensor": None, "remote": None", "mark": None, "duration": None }
```

Then you can do:

```
DBTable.DBField = item.get(j, defaults)["sensor"]
```

You could also use a `collections.defaultdict` for the defaults item, which will allow you to provide a default for any key accessed.

Comment: That seems like a brilliant idea. But I don't know yet, if i can get json to construct defaultdicts instead of dicts. I will investigate this.

Answer (score 1):

May be this would work

```
for item in sensors["measurements"]:
 for j in range(len(sensors["measurements"])):
     try:
        DBTable.DBField = item[j]["sensor"]
     except:
        DBTable.DBField = None
```

Comment: Yes, this works (tested). But this data structure can become huge (>200 different fields like "sensor") and doing so, makes the code quite bloated because every field needs this construct.